# Relation between $C_0^\infty$ and $BMO$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I know that $C_0^\infty$ is not dense in $BMO$, as the space $C_0$ of continuous functions vanishing at infinity is closed in $VMO\subset BMO$. However, I was wondering if it is dense in $BMO$ with respect to the weak-* topology.

My approach:
Let $f\in BMO$ and $g\in\mathcal{H}_a^1$ - a dense subspace of $\mathcal{H}^1$ of bounded functions with compact support. I will approximate $f$ by $f_\varepsilon=f\ast\eta_\varepsilon$, where $\eta_\varepsilon$ is a standard mollifier. By Fubini's theorem we have
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (f\ast\eta_\varepsilon)g \; \mathrm{d}x = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(g\ast\eta_\varepsilon) \; \mathrm{d}x. $$
Now as $f\in L_{loc}^1$ and $g\in L^\infty$ I can use the fact that $g\ast\eta_\varepsilon$ approximates $g$ in $L^\infty$ with weak-* topology and then
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(g\ast\eta_\varepsilon) \; \mathrm{d}x \to \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} fg \; \mathrm{d}x. $$

But here's the key problem: can I conclude from this the convergence for all $g\in\mathcal{H}^1$? As $f_\varepsilon g$ and $fg$ might not necessarily be in $L^1$, the linear functional associated with $f$ is not defined by the integral and I don't know much about it.

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: BMO,VMO, $\mathcal{H}_a^1$ ?

Comment: It's a general fact that if $X$ is a Banach space with dual $X'$, and if $\ell_k, \ell\in X'$ are such that $\| \ell_k\|_{X'}, \| \ell\|_{X'} \leq C$ (uniformly in $k$) and $\ell_k(x)\to \ell(x)$ for $x$ on a dense subset of $X$, then $\ell_k\to \ell$ weak-*.

Comment: @Jose27 thanks for your comment, it solves my problem :)